# How to launch an application from a contact in Android?

Tags: android, contacts

I would like to write an application which would be launched from the Contacts list in the phone. That is, you choose a contact using the normal contacts application, and where you can dial to the contact, send an Email or SMS, you can also launch my application with this contact's activity.
How can this be done?

Comment: I don't know how it is done but you should somehow be able to integrate in the quick contacts menu like the facebook app, meebo or other apps. This would enable the user to longpress on a contact and start your app from the menu that is opening.

Answer (score 2):

With the default Android source Contact application you can't do it.

If the phone has some other 3rd party Contact's application, and that has a way to be extended by plugins, you can write this plugin to respond by openning your application.